# Движение элемента по кругу

Tags: javascript, html, css3, анимация, css-animation

Как выполнить бесконечное движение шарика по кругу?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrp {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: antiquewhite;
  border: 1px solid burlywood;
}

.ball {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: chocolate;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrp">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="ball"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать CSS анимацию, с помощью правила `@keyframes` установить общие ключевые кадры. Такой вариант анимации является совсем не сложным, поэтому достаточно использовать ключевые слова `from` и `to`. Получить такую анимацию нам помогут свойства `rotate` и `translateY`. Вот пример такой анимации:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrp {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: antiquewhite;
  border: 1px solid burlywood;
}

.ball {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: chocolate;
  animation: animate 2s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.26, 0.4, 0.82) infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-60px);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translateY(-60px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrp">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="ball"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Или в обратную сторону:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrp {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: antiquewhite;
  border: 1px solid burlywood;
}

.ball {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: chocolate;
  animation: animate 2s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.26, 0.4, 0.82) infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translateY(-60px);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-60px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrp">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="ball"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrp {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: antiquewhite;
  border: 1px solid burlywood;
}

.ball {
  margin: calc(50% - 10px) auto 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: chocolate;
  animation: spin 3s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0turn) translateY(-70px) translateY(50%) rotate(1turn)
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(1turn) translateY(-70px) translateY(50%) rotate(0turn);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrp">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="ball"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```